# Adding new keys generated by a variable to a object in Vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, object, vue.js

Building a project using Vue.js (and Laravel), the following (greatly simplified) code results in the below error:

**Vue component:**

```
<template>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="main_object[item_id][my_answer_key]">
</template>

<script>
    export default {

        props: [

        ],

        data() {
            return {
                main_object: {},
                item_id: '1234',
                my_answer_key: '5678'
            }
        },

        ready: function () {
            vm = this;
        },

        methods: {

        }
    }

</script>
```

**Error received:**

[image]

We know you can use the vm.$set() method to add properties to the object. However, we’re building the model path on the fly (item_id and my_answer_key change depending on various user options being selected).  It seems like we have to write a method that determines if the object property is already set, and if it's not set, to then set it.  Is there a better way to accomplish the above?

Comment: *and if it's not set, to then set it* What do you want to set it to? Where does the value come from?

Comment: We want to set it to the v-model path

Comment: `Vue.set( object, key, value )` may be helpful to you, since you can update only the keys you want on the fly https://vuejs.org/api/#Vue-set

Answer (score 0):

You could seemingly get around this by using the `created` hook and `$set`:

```
created: function () {
    this.$set(this.item_id + "." + this.my_answer_key, "")
}
```

However, if item_id and my_answer_key can change, this approach will ultimately not work because Vue does not have *dynamic* two way binding. In other words, the binding in your v-model will be created once and will not change later if either of the `item_id` or `my_answer_key` values change.

So, to accomplish something like this, you might need to resort to a kludge like using a `v-if` and toggling it to destroy and recreate the input (and it's binding). That might work.

Sometimes, computed's can help with these situations. Bind your input to a simple attribute on your data model and use a computed to generate the actual nested data model you need elsewhere.